# Can't figure out error log when installing Django on fastCGI apache server

Tags: python, django, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I get this error from the error log when trying to install Django on a FastCGI apache server.

```
[Tue Feb 19 10:28:54 2013] [warn] [client 74.59.229.207] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Tue Feb 19 10:28:54 2013] [error] [client 74.59.229.207] Premature end of script headers: mysite.fcgi
[Tue Feb 19 10:28:54 2013] [error] [client 74.59.229.207] Premature end of script headers: 500.php
```

I don't understand if the problem come from the server settings or my .fcgi code.

**.htaccess**

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(adminmedia/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(mysite.fcgi)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

**mysite.fcgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, "/home2/lacliniq/opt/python27/bin/python")
sys.path.insert(1, "/home2/lacliniq/opt/python27/lib")

os.chdir("/home2/lacliniq/public_html/checkupappdev")

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "firstaid.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

I feel like the .fcgi code is ok since it run as expected when run from shell.
If someone could help me get on the right path, it would really help out!

Answer (score 4):

Like Jordan said, it's a problem with the fcgi file.

I was having the same problem trying to get Django working on bluehost. A couple of things to check first are that the fcgi file is set to 755 and make sure your settings file is properly formatted by using:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

If those things are OK, try the solution I found at https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/585.  From the directions there:

```
cd <fcgi directory>
unset PYTHONPATH
./mysite.fcgi
```

If you get a error like:

```
bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

it means that the shebang (#!) line points to a file or directory that doesn't exist or that the fcgi was uploaded via ftp in binary mode instead of ascii.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing "the point of view": run the fcgi file as apache user (I'm sure there will be some interesting messages displayed).
E.g.

```
$ sudo su www-data
$ cd <fcgi directory>
$ ./mysite.fcgi
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a problem with your .fcgi file, or even more likely, some trouble configuring your django site.

Try running your .fcgi directly in a shell with ./mysite.fcgi. It should spit out some errors, which will give you something to troubleshoot with.

Comment: Well that's where I am confused. If I run the script in shell I get the normal django debug page for an error 404, which is to be expected because I don't have an index - technically it is correct.
But I do get this error:

Comment: `WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!`

Comment: Which should be self-explanatory but I don't know where I am suppose to define those parameters.